# Socket.io and session data

Tags: session, node.js, socket.io

Is this a suitable way of storing my temporary app data?

```
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 
  client.myappsdata = {
    a: true,
    b: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer something slightly more heavy.

**Pseudo-Code:**

```
// ClientManager.js
var Manager = new function() {
    this._clients = [];

    this.set = function(client, data) {
        this._clients[client.sessionId] = data;    
    };

    this.get = function(client) {
        return this._clients[client.sessionId];            
    }

};

module.exports = function() {
    return Object.create(Manager);
};

// main.js
var manager = require("ClientManager")();

/* ... */

socket.on("connection", function(client) {
    manager.set(client, {
       /* ... */ 
    });
}
```

Bassically each client has a `sessionId` so store their data in a hash keyed by that sessionId

Comment: Any reason not to do it how I am doing it?

Comment: @Thomas the above method is more extensible. Also I would have to hunt all over the socket.io code to make sure that the `client` object is passed around everywhere. What I do know is that the `sessionId` is safe to use a key/hash to attach to a client. So store data in a hash keyed by the sessionId

Comment: @Raynos with your solution, you have to pass the client everywhere as well, because both get and set methods have the client object as first parameter, isn't it? That is, IMO , normal and not avoidable, because we have to got a reference of the client to get its data.

Comment: @Qlimax I know this is almost a year later but the code doesn't rely on the client instance itself, it grabs the sessionId property from the client object and uses that NOT the actual client instance. The difference being that socket.io may not pass the same client instance around all the time, simply creating "socket" objects with the same sessionId. Raynos' code works even if thats the case because it bases it's hash of the sessionId (a string) and not the client object